# Grails + hibernate + controller sessionFactory null object?

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, grails, orm

I am new to using hibernate and grails. I have multiple java objects that I need to persist. To learn how it works I'm using a simple example of an employee class. Its in my src/java with the corresponding xml mappings with it. I think I need to make a session instance from my session factory, and I do not know what I'm doing wrong. I followed a tutorial for setting up hibternate [hibernate tut](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_pdf_version.htm) and tried to translate it for grails. Any thoughts?

```
package com.turingpages.Matrix.view

import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH


class MatrixController {

    def ctx = AH.application.mainContext
    def sessionFactory = ctx.sessionFactory

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

...

    def create() {
        def session = sessionFactory.currentSession
        Transaction tx = null;
        Integer employeeID = null;
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Employee employee = new Employee("fname", "lname", 100);
            employeeID = (Integer) session.save(employee);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return employeeID;
    }
```

My stack trace:

```
 ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [POST] /turingpages/matrix/create
Cannot get property 'currentSession' on null object. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot get property 'currentSession' on null object
    Line | Method
->>   33 | create    in com.turingpages.Matrix.view.MatrixController$$ENvP7skK
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    195 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason you should be writing code like that with Grails.  If you really need to manage the transaction in a controller, you should do it this way.

```
def create() {
    Integer employeeID = null;
    Employee.withTransaction { status ->
      Employee employee = new Employee(firstName: "fname", lastName: "lname", noIdea: 100);
      employee.save()
      if (employee.hasErrors()) {
         status.setRollbackOnly()
      }
    }
    return employee.id;
}
```

That said, when dealing with a single Domain like this, you don't really need to worry about it at all:

```
def create() {
   Employee employee = new Employee(firstName: "fname", lastName: "lname", noIdea: 100);
   employee.save(flush: true)
   [employee: employee] // generally you want to pass the object back to a view this way
   // deal with errors in the domain on the view
}
```

And even better would be to use a [Service](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html) class.  But that can be your homework assignment.

Comment: +1, actually `new Employee("fname", "lname", 100)` is also wrong.

Comment: If I use that code, I get a no method exception on  `static matrices.Employee.withTransaction()`. Employee is a java class in src/java and I have the corresponding XML mappings in the same location.

Comment: Is this because you can't change Employee into a grails Domain or is this because you didn't think you could?

Comment: I'm trying employee as a simple example to see how this works. I have a lot of java objects already written that I want to persist.

Comment: You should add that to your question then.  Be as detailed as you can when asking questions, otherwise you get crystal ball answers.

Comment: I update my question to reflect these details, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the code

```
def ctx = AH.application.mainContext
def sessionFactory = ctx.sessionFactory
```

into the method create(), or replace it with

```
def sessionFactory
```

However, Grails provides a [withTransaction](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html) method to serve your purpose in a simpler way:

```
    def create() {
        Employee.withTransaction{ status ->
            Employee employee = new Employee("fname", "lname", 100).save()
            .....
            if (employee.id) {
                return employee.id
            }
            else {
               status.setRollbackOnly()
            }
        }
    }
```